# Query fetching all the posts of the users I am following and my own post

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables

1. User > `id, username, name, age, sex, location`
2. User Post > `id, user_id, description, image, postime, location`
3. Follow > `id, user_id, follow_id, status`

In User table I will be having all the user information.

In User Post table I will be having all the post related information.

I want to display my own post and also post of the users I am following

The query I had written for this situation is

```
SELECT 
  u.username,
  u.name,
  u.profile_pic, 
  up.* 
 FROM user u, user_post up 
 WHERE (up.user_id  = $user_id OR up.user_id IN 
       (SELECT user_id 
        FROM follow WHERE follow_id=$user_id)), $user_id) 
        AND description='' group by id order by postime desc
```

I feel the query is wrong, can anyone help me

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `age` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `deviceToken` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_post` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `postime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `follow` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `follow_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pending',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: That's the same question you posted yesterday and you still don't show the table definition, etc.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you're asking...Have you tested the query?  What are you getting vs what's expected?

Comment: Yesterday's answers did not helped me, all giving wrong output

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `follow` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `follow_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pending',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  ;

Comment: Without knowing your actual data and the FKs between your tables one can only guess (and based on that guess my answer from yesterday was correct).

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_post` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `postime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `age` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `deviceToken` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

Comment: Now you only need to add some info about foreign keys. Btw, `age`and `gender` are `VARCHAR`?

Comment: actually age and gender are not varchar, I will change it

Comment: user table id is base foreign key in all the tables (user_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same answer I posted yesterday:

```
SELECT u.username,u.name,u.profile_pic, up.* 
FROM user u JOIN user_post up 
  ON up.user_id = u.id
WHERE 
   (up.user_id  = $user_id 
    OR
    up.user_id IN (
                     SELECT user_id 
                     FROM follow 
                     WHERE follow_id=$user_id
                   )
   )
AND description='' 
ORDER BY postime DESC
```

As you didn't tell about the relations between user and follower it might enough to switch `follow_id`and `user_id`:

```
SELECT u.username,u.name,u.profile_pic, up.* 
FROM user u JOIN user_post up 
  ON up.user_id = u.id
WHERE 
   (up.user_id  = $user_id 
    OR
    up.user_id IN (
                     SELECT follow_id
                     FROM follow 
                     WHERE user_id=$user_id
                   )
   )
AND description='' 
ORDER BY postime DESC
```

Comment: If I (21) follow user 20 then follow_id = 21 and user_id=20

Comment: user 21 is following user 20 thats the logic

Comment: Thanks brother for your help :) this works fine for me  SELECT u.username, u.name, u.profile_pic, up . * 
FROM user u
JOIN user_post up ON up.user_id = u.id
WHERE (
up.user_id =21
OR up.user_id
IN (

SELECT user_id
FROM follow
WHERE follow_id =21
)
)
AND description =  ''
ORDER BY postime DESC

Comment: @SubramanianRaj: But this is exactly the query I posted yesterday?